# Default layout Corruption using WYIWYG editor, "Cant Load Jquery" Error

Tags: octobercms

The Problem occurred while I was configuring my October CMS to use WYSIWYG editor from settings.

The Default layout was working fine. But as soon as I opened the default layout file, the WYSIWYG editor ( I Think) changed some code and now my CMS is not able to load any styles.
I tried to recreate the default layout file. But The console Throws an error

```
*framework.js:9 Uncaught Error: The jQuery library is not loaded. 
The OctoberCMS framework cannot be initialized.
at framework.js:9*
```

Which means somehow October is not able to load Jquery Now.
My Default Layout looks like this after my own editing.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ this.page.title }}</title>
{% styles %}
{% framework extras %} {% scripts %}
</head>
<body>
{% partial "site/header" %}
{% page %}
{% partial "site/footer" %}
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to shift the scripts tag to bottom but didn't help.
The default layout should be able to load the required file.

Edit:

Ok, I was able to fix that the hard way(reinstalling).
The actual layout file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>October CMS - {{ this.page.title }}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}">
<meta name="title" content="{{ this.page.meta_title }}">
<meta name="author" content="OctoberCMS">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="generator" content="OctoberCMS">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="{{ 'assets/images/october.png'|theme }}">
 <link href="{{ 'assets/css/vendor.css'|theme }}" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="{{ 'assets/css/theme.css'|theme }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% styles %}
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<header id="layout-header">
{% partial 'site/header' %}
</header>

<!-- Content -->
<section id="layout-content">
{% page %}
</section>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="layout-footer">
{% partial 'site/footer' %}
</footer>

<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ 'assets/vendor/jquery.js'|theme }}"></script>
<script src="{{ 'assets/vendor/bootstrap.js'|theme }}"></script>
<script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/app.js'|theme }}"></script>
{% framework extras %}
{% scripts %}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess you are missing `<script src="{{ 'assets/javascript/jquery-3.2.1.js'|theme }}"></script>` as framework do not load `jQuery it self` so try to add jQuery before the `{% framework extras %}`

Comment: Not working as "assets/javascript/ " folder doesn't contain jquery. However I tried pasting the CDN of jquery itself , but it is also not working.

Comment: Thanks hardik, your comment was almost right.